# How do I replace a table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, ddl, locks

Basically I want to do this:

```
begin;
lock table a;
alter table a rename to b;
alter table a1 rename to a;
drop table b;
commit;
```

i.e. gain control and replace my old table while no one has access to it.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding where you are stuck or what you cannot seem to be able to achieve?

Comment: Not so much.  I got an error when I tried it at the command line but there may have been an existing table or something that caused it and I misinterpreted it.  Therefore you have the best answer. ;-)

Comment: Then please specify the error you are obtaining.

Answer (score 19):

Simpler:

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE a;
ALTER TABLE a1 RENAME TO a;
COMMIT;
```

`DROP TABLE` acquires an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table anyway. An explicit `LOCK` command is no better. And renaming a dead guy is just a waste of time.

You may want to write-lock the old table while *preparing* the new, to prevent writes in between. Then you'd issue a lock like this earlier in the process:

```
LOCK TABLE a IN SHARE MODE;
```

What happens to concurrent transactions trying to access the table? It's not that simple, read this:

- [Best way to populate a new column in a large table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52531/3684)

Explains why you may have seen error messages like this:

> ```
> ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 123456
> ```

Comment: Also note that neither this nor the original solution will preserve `FOREIGN KEY` constraints referencing the table, views referencing the table, etc. The `DROP` will fail. If you `DROP ... CASCADE` then the referencing views, constraints, etc are dropped, and will not be recreated when you create / rename the replacement table into place. There is not currently a convenient way to "swap" two tables and keep FK constraints etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create SQL-backup, make changes you need directly at the backup.sql file and restore database. I used this trick when have added INHERIT for group of tables (Postgres dbms) to remove inherited fields from subtable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use answer#13, but I agree, it will not inherit the constraints, and drop table might fail

- line up the relevant constraints first (like from pg_dump --schema-only,
- drop the constraints
- do the swap per answer#13
- apply the constraints (sql snippets from the schema dump)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30013857)