# Replace rows from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with exactly same columns. First one is used for production, web application(django) is retrieving objects from it to show on webpage.
And I am using Python script for adding objects to the second one.
When script is done I need to replace all rows in table-1 with rows from table-2. Right now I am using something like this:

```
TRUNCATE table-1;
INSERT INTO table-1 (columns) SELECT columns FROM table-2;
TRUNCATE table-2;
VACUUM FULL;
```

Problem is that it taking too long time and after TRUNCATE table-1 website is just useless until INSERT is done. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Use `delete` instead of `truncate` for table_1. That will allow read access to `table_1` until you commit.

Comment: add `where` statement, assuming insert is too long because the tables are big

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a view and code django against that. When it's time to cut over between table1 and table2, just `create or replace view` to switch to the  other table instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the expensive `VACUUM FULL` at all. Right after your big `INSERT` there is nothing to clean up. No dead tuples, and all indexes are in pristine condition.

It can make sense to run [`ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-analyze.html) though to update completely changed table statistics right away.

For small tables `DELETE` can be faster than `TRUNCATE`, but for medium to large tables `TRUNCATE` is typically faster.

And do it all in a single transaction. `INSERT` after `TRUNCATE` in the same transaction does not have to write to WAL and is much faster:

```
BEGIN;
TRUNCATE table1;
INSERT INTO table1 TABLE table2;
TRUNCATE table2;  -- do you need this?
ANALYZE table1;  -- might be useful 
COMMIT;
```

Details:

- [What causes large INSERT to slow down and disk usage to explode?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114926/3684)

If you have any indexes on `table1` it pays to drop them first and recreate them after the `INSERT` for big tables.

If you don't have depending objects, you might also just drop `table1` and rename `table2`, which would be *much* faster.

- [How do I replace a table in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405441/how-do-i-replace-a-table-in-postgres/32406198#32406198)

Either method requires an **exclusive lock** on the table. But you have been using [`VACUUM FULL` previously which takes an exclusive lock as well:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-vacuum.html)

> `VACUUM FULL` rewrites the entire contents of the table into a new disk
>   file with no extra space, allowing unused space to be returned to the
>   operating system. This form is much slower and requires an exclusive
>   lock on each table while it is being processed.

So it's safe to assume an exclusive lock is ok for you.

Comment: But `truncate` will acquire an access exclusive lock on the table, so that during the transaction, the table can't even be read (and my understanding was, that that is the problem)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I don't think it would make any sense to allow concurrent reads while rewriting the table completely. So this is a *feature*, not a bug.

Comment: I never said it's a bug. But until the whole process of replacing the data is finished, I do think it can make sense to allow clients to see the previous (consistent) state of the table. After all that's what transactions are made for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: transactions "are made" for many purposes. Once I decide to replace the contents of a table I probably do *not* want any more concurrent transactions to read the old contents while I'm at it.

Comment: Depends on the requirement. We actually do have some tables (that store e.g. aggregated data) were we implement precisely this. We even do this with multiple tables in a single transaction (e.g. for a content management system when publishing the content from the staging to the live environment). I don't find this requirement particularly surprising ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's also not in the question. I think my assumption is more likely when replacing the whole table. Even for `DELETE` I would take an exclusive lock on the table first to rule out intermediary states and avoid interlocking with concurrent transactions. I stated that an exclusive lock is necessary. If the OP has different requirements, (s)he has to tell us.

Comment: I need to have read access to the table during transaction. Because it make sense to have access to the previous state of table while updating in my app. So I will try to merge @ykaganovich solution with single transaction method from you to be as fast as possible with it. Both answers are good for me so I will implement it tomorrow and probably post my own answer with both solutions merged. Thanks a lot! :)